# Resizing active form in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the game Catch me if you can.
At the moment the size is static. We can play the game only in static height/width. 
How can i create that the button goes to different coordinates when WindowsForm is sized to maximum size? 
Sorry for bad explaining, hope you understand :S

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.MouseEnter += button1_MouseEnter;
    button1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    button1.Text = "Noķer";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.MouseEnter -= button1_MouseEnter;
    button1.Text = "gatavs";
    button1.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;

}

private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    button1.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(12, 197), rnd.Next(12, 226));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    button1.Location = new Point(
         rnd.Next(0, this.ClientRectangle.Width- this.button1.Width),
         rnd.Next(0,this.ClientRectangle.Height- this.button1.Height));
}
```

This way you will be sure that the button never goes beyond forms borders. If you don't subtract button width and height from the maximum width and height, then some parts of button may goes beyond the forms border.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed :P

Answer (score 2):

If i understand what do you want to say, you can pass actual size of form in Point method like this:

```
button1.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(12, this.Size.Height), rnd.Next(12, this.Size.Width));
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is something close to what i want, but you can try the code urself and see that button dissapears and doesn't work properly